# How can I shuffle data in csv file?

Tags: dataframe, csv, random, jupyter-notebook, shuffle

[I have the following dataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFOxr.png)

The data is from csv file and I would like to shuffle in each rows

this is my code that I imported csv file

```
    df = pd.read_csv('data1.csv',header=None, names=cols)
    df1 = df[['kac']]
    print(df1)
```

how can i do this?

I want to shuffled rows of csv file

Comment: From Googling: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pandas-how-to-shuffle-a-dataframe-rows/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is straightforward :

```
df_shuffled = df.sample(frac=1, random_state=42).reset_index(drop=True)
```

But there is an basic concept in it!
Let's talk about what is real random and what is the pheroaradom.

True random numbers:

- Randomness: which means each number is independent of each other and will be selected with equal probability.
- Unpredictability: This is easy to understand, you can never predict the next value arose from random number generator.
- Non-reproducibility: This means the number you create can't be recreated again.

Pseudorandom numbers which has the randomness property but can't ensure either Unpredictability or Non-reproducibility

Then next question-> Does normal computer generates the true random number?

> Normal computer can't generate the random number. The normal method
> adopt a random seed and then use some algorithm
> (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) to
> generate the "random" numbers which is not meet the
> Non-reproducibility property.

Then next, is there any other way to generate the true random number? if have why not we use that way to generate the random number for our daily coding?

> Yes we can use some hardware to help us to generate some random factor
> to generate the true random number, but it will cost too much
> to generate it or it is too slow to generate it.

Hence, unless your algorithm or scenario is related to encryption, there is no need to use true random numbers.

So even the question has been answered, we may also want to dig into the detail to truly understand how it works. Especially, this concept is very basic and important in our coding life.

I wish this will help you in the future. And if i am wrong, please let me know, I will modify the answer.

Abbreviations:

- Pseudorandom Number Generators (PRNGs)
- True Random Number Generators (TRNGs)